# Permission Report for Specific User in a Site Collection using Power Shell instead of PNP

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I need a help with Power Shell. We need to find out all the sites(possibly with lists and libraries and sub-sites too) a user have permissions to. Can we do this with Power Shell? If not are there any workarounds for this? Note :- See if we can generate a script with regular Power Shell instead of PNP.

I am open to suggestions. Let me know.

Comment: This thread https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/09/sharepoint-online-get-user-permission-report-using-powershell.html

Comment: Hey thanks for your contribution but i need the script which uses only powershell and not the pnp. can u look into this.

Comment: The script not use pnp, just using CSOM api.

Comment: yes, the other requirement is we need to use only powershell and the SP online management shell. But that code is not working. I tried do you have the implemented code to do.